# Submit command line // submit unfilled raw_input

Tags: python

I'm looking to write a program that asks for `user_input` on a cyclical basis, but does not halt further procedures while waiting for the user to give input.

---

Is there a command that acts as a press of the RETURN key?  Does this have to do with writing to stdin?  An alternative might be to see if there is no `user_input` that currently exists.

---

Imagine operating the code below, where the program is constantly running, even if the user provides no input,

```
import os
import time
import termios
import sys

x = 0

while x < 60:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x += 1
    print x

    user_input = raw_input(" ")

    if user_input == "exit":
        os._exit(1)
```

Comment: You can do this with a thread.

Comment: You will need [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python) for this. Probably not worth the fuss though.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164619/4014959) a demo I wrote that processes user input while performing another task in a separate thread.

Comment: I'd really like to divert the conversation away from multithreading, as this appears to be the most complicated solution to my dilemma.  It appears to me that there ought to be an extremely simple solution here.  Perhaps all I should need to do is to submit <code> /n </code> to the terminal?

Comment: You don't need threading. You can use the `select` or `selectors` module to check the standard input every so often, with a timeout. If nothing is available, just keep doing the other work. If something is available, read it and respond accordingly.